# Async iterative to update UI

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, android-asynctask, server, client

I have one problem. I want to update the state of a switch on the main UI on the base of what I receive from a server. As we know, android not allow the internet connection on main thread.

So I used Async. Unfortunately, inside of Async i'm not able to modify the UI. I would like an AsyncTask that do a "while(true)" with my code inside. It ask the server and on the base of reply update the UI ever and ever.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English!

Edit: I'm talking of an Android application.

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) has methods that intended to work with UI, for example [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)). But AsyncTask should only be used for operations that take quite few seconds and may hang other AsyncTasks. So

> do a "while(true)" with my code inside

is not an option. For chatting with server you may want to use [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Check more information about processes and some [gotchas](http://mgolokhov.github.io/processes_and_threads/).

Comment: I solved by doing a while(true) inside a thread that calls AsyncTask. Actually, I don't know if it is an acceptable way to do this! Let me know!

Comment: AsyncTasks are executed serially on a single background thread (from API 11), that's why long running worker can block others.

Comment: I know, so it's better to use service? Right?

Comment: I would use service.